# Why does geopandas throw an assertion error, when the conditions seems to be met?

Tags: python, conda, assert, geopandas

I am trying to make a WFS request and create a GeoDataFrame (from the **geopandas** library) with this data. However, when I run my code, an `assert` raises an error:

```
assert len(bbox) == 4
```

I do not know what is causing this error, as when I print `bb` I get a string of four coordinates separated by a comma:

```
print(bb)
173600,443600,174600,444600

type(bb)
str
```

This is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from requests import Request

# extract only buildings on and around WUR campus
url = 'https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs'
layer = 'bag:pand' # see wfs.contents
bb = ','.join(map(str, bbox)) # string of bbox needed for the request url

# Specify the parameters for fetching the data
params = dict(service='WFS', version="2.0.0", request='GetFeature',
      typeName=layer, outputFormat='text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2',
      srsname='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992', bbox=bb)

# Parse the URL with parameters
q = Request('GET', url, params=params).prepare().url

# Read data from URL
BuildingsGDF = gpd.read_file(q)
```

The last line (`BuildingsGDF = gdp.read_file(q)`) throws the error from the assertion, i.e. when I try to read the result of a WFS request into a GeoDataFrame object (from the geopandas library).

I am working in a Conda environment, which has the following packages:

```
#  packages in environment at /home/sytze/miniconda3/envs/geoscripting:

#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main    conda-forge
affine                    2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
altair                    3.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
astroid                   2.3.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
branca                    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0  
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0  
cffi                      1.13.1           py37h2e261b9_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                    py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              2.8              py37h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.65.3               hbc83047_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_3    conda-forge
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fiona                     1.8.8                    pypi_0    pypi
folium                    0.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
freexl                    1.0.5                h14c3975_0  
gdal                      2.3.3            py37hbb2a789_0  
geographiclib             1.50                       py_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
geopy                     1.20.0                     py_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.7.1                he6710b0_0  
giflib                    5.1.4                h14c3975_1  
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
hdf4                      4.2.13               h3ca952b_2  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      243  
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.9.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
jeepney                   0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json-c                    0.13.1               h1bed415_0  
jsonschema                3.1.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.0                    py37_0  
kealib                    1.4.7                hd0c454d_6  
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he6710b0_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               h173b8e3_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.2            py37h7b6447c_0  
libboost                  1.67.0               h46d08c1_4  
libcurl                   7.65.3               h20c2e04_0  
libdap4                   3.19.1               h6ec2957_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgdal                   2.3.3                h2e7e64b_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libkml                    1.3.0                h590aaf7_4  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h11d0813_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libpq                     11.2                 h20c2e04_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libspatialindex           1.8.5                h20b78c2_2  
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hb08deb6_19  
libssh2                   1.8.2                h1ba5d50_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.0.10               h2733197_2  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h7d1a2b0_0  
lxml                      4.4.1            py37hefd8a0e_0  
mapclassify               2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h5429711_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      243  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0  
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0  
munch                     2.3.2                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.0                    py37_1    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.17.2           py37haad9e8e_0  
numpy-base                1.17.2           py37hde5b4d6_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h05c96fa_1  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h7b6447c_3  
osmnx                     0.10                       py_1    conda-forge
owslib                    0.18.0                     py_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.2                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.25.2           py37he6710b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
poppler                   0.65.0               h581218d_1  
poppler-data              0.4.9                         0    conda-forge
progressbar2              3.37.1                   py37_0  
proj4                     5.2.0                he6710b0_1  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
psycopg2                  2.8.3            py37h1ba5d50_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.4.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.6            py37h14380d9_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2  
pyrsistent                0.15.4           py37h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
pytest                    5.3.2                    py37_0  
pytest-runner             5.2                        py_0  
python                    3.7.5                h0371630_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-utils              2.3.0                    py37_0  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37he6710b0_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
rasterio                  1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rasterstats               0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.8.3                    py37_0  
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h7c811a0_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
secretstorage             3.1.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                41.6.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4            py37h86c5351_0  
simplejson                3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
snuggs                    1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinx                    2.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.3.10           py37h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37hdd07704_0  
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
vincent                   0.4.4                      py_1    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h7b6447c_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2                h780794e_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Comment: Your `bb` string does not have length 4. And you pass it to your function, so it checks the length of `bb`, which is more than 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a list with four elements, you have a string.

To solve this, split your string to create a list before the assert, like `bb = bb.split(',')`.